# Unable to insert data to MongoDB from Spark without MongoSpark

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

What I'm trying to achieve here is to insert several documents into a given collection for several databases.

The database is different depending on a given attribute within the object, so each of them should choose from a small cache Map with (key, MongoCollection [pointing to its respective DB, not always the same]) the one they need and `.insertOne` with the Document.

The problem I'm finding with this is that `MongoCollectionImpl` seems to be not serializable when performing the following action (simplified, but which replicates the error)...

```
.map(
  MongoClient(s"mongodb://localhost:27017")
    .getDatabase("sample")
    .getCollection("sample_collection")
    .insertOne)
```

I know that there is a connector specifically made for Spark within MongoDB, but I can't make my mind up how to use more than one DB, as I would need several WriteConfig that should be applied conditionally to each of the elements, so they aren't inserted in another DB they shouldn't be in.

https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/scala/write-to-mongodb/

Is there any workaround related to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `MongoSpark` connector and partition / split your original dataframe based on a condition.

```scala
myDataFrame.cache() // recommended to prevent repeating the calculation

val df1 = myDataFrame.filter('myColumn < 0)
val df2 = myDataFrame.filter('myColumn >= 0 && 'myColumn < 50)
val df3 = myDataFrame.filter('myColumn >= 50 )

MongoSpark.save(df1.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite), WriteConfig(databaseName = ???, collectionName = ???, connectionString = Some(???))

MongoSpark.save(df2.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite), WriteConfig(databaseName = ???, collectionName = ???, connectionString = Some(???))

MongoSpark.save(df3.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite), WriteConfig(databaseName = ???, collectionName = ???, connectionString = Some(???))
```

Comment: I was thinking about that also, but I'm afraid of the size in memory... Would it be feasible to do it with +70 DFs?

Comment: The amount of dataframes shouldn't matter. The cache of the original dataframe will be default MEMORY_AND_DISK, making sure that original data that can't be kept in memory can be spilled to disk. To keep it concise, you could create a Map[Column,WriteConfig], where the Column contains the filter and the WriteConfig the database config and then `foreach` over this map